# Recyclerview with two ViewTypes from two SQL Tables/ Cursors: What is the best way?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to build an app with a recyclerview and different viewstypes from different data sources. For one input array/ sql table there are many questions/ answers here. I know. But let me start to explain: :)

My goal is that the app shows an *event* as a header with imformation like: *title, location, date, and so on*. Under this there should be a gridview with *images* of the *event*. There can be many *events* with many *pictures* each.

[Picture of App Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFpCQ.jpg)

The data are stored inside a sql database in two tabels: one for the *events* and one for the *images*. There are connected via id. At the moment the image are text, just to get the structure right first.

My problem is that I don't know what is the best way to structure this code. I thought about within the RecyclerView Adapter (EventAdapter.java) I use getItemViewType() to differ between the views.

1. But because of the two tables I would need two cursors. This doesn't work (or I don't get how).
2. If I join the tables I don't have that problem but instead I have to call differenent views from one dataset/ row with join data. So this is not a solution either.
3. I transfer my two tables to a custom array first and try then to process it. I haven't tried it yet but it sounds wrong because of the different attributes from my tables.

Another way would be to work with sections. But I think I have the same problem with the two tables there.

So maybe this is a easy problem for others, and I just don't get it, but I'm starting to learn.. and maybe someone can give me the right hint how I can structure this.

Here are my codes so far. I shortened it, normally there would be some input methods and button functions. But I think this is the gist. Also at the EventAdapter.java there is no code to differ between the views. I remove it because it was ****.... :(

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


     //SQL
    EventDBHelper dpHelper = new EventDBHelper(this);
    mDatabase = dpHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 
}

public static Cursor getAllItems(){

    return mDatabase.query(
            EventContract.EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_USERDATE + " DESC"
    );

}
public static Cursor getAllImages(){
    return mDatabase.query(
            EventContract.EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME_IMAGE,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
    );
}}
```

EventDBHelper.java

```
public class EventDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eventlist.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public EventDBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_EVENTLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            EventViewEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_USERDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_NOTES + " TEXT NULL" +
            ");";
    final String SQL_CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME_IMAGE + " (" +
            EventViewEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_ID_EVENT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
            ");";
   
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_EVENTLIST_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME_IMAGE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}}
```

EventViewFragment.java

```
public class EventViewFragment extends Fragment {

private static EventAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_view, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity(), getAllItems(), getAllImages());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

  public static void saveInDB(...) {

    //save event
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    cv.put(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION, location);
    cv.put(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_USERDATE, date);
    Long id_event = mDatabase.insert(EventContract.EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    //save image
    ContentValues cv_image = new ContentValues();
    cv_image.put(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME, image);
    cv_image.put(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_ID_EVENT, id_event);
    mDatabase.insert(EventContract.EventViewEntry.TABLE_NAME_IMAGE, null, cv_image);
    

    mAdapter.swapCurser(getAllItems());
    mAdapter.swapCurserImage(getAllImages());

}}
```

EventAdapter.java

```
public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.EventViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCurser;
private Cursor mCurserImage;
private int id;
private String image;

public EventAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, Cursor curserImage) {
    mContext = context;
    mCurser = cursor;
    mCurserImage = curserImage;
}

public class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleText;
    public TextView locationText;
    public TextView dateText;
    public TextView idText;
    public TextView imageAsText;


    public EventViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_one_title);
        locationText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_one_location);
        dateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_one_date);
        idText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_one_id);
        imageAsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_image);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //do something to get different views

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view_item, parent, false);
    return new EventViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //do something to set the different tables

    if (!mCurser.moveToPosition(position)){
        return;
    }

    String title = mCurser.getString(mCurser.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));
    String location = mCurser.getString(mCurser.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION));
    String date = mCurser.getString(mCurser.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_USERDATE));
    id = mCurser.getInt(mCurser.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry._ID));

    holder.titleText.setText(title);
    holder.locationText.setText(location);
    holder.notesText.setText((notes));
    holder.dateText.setText(date);
    holder.idText.setTag(id);

    //image
    if (mCurserImage.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (Integer.toString(id).equals(mCurserImage.getString(mCurserImage.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_ID_EVENT)))){
                image = mCurserImage.getString(mCurserImage.getColumnIndex(EventContract.EventViewEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME));
            }

        } while (mCurserImage.moveToNext());
    }
    holder.imageAsText.setText(image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCurser.getCount();

}

public void swapCurser(Cursor newCurser){
    if(mCurser != null){
        mCurser.close();
    }
    mCurser = newCurser;

    if (newCurser != null){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
public void swapCurserImage(Cursor newCurser){
    if(mCurserImage != null){
        mCurserImage.close();
    }
    mCurserImage = newCurser;

    if (newCurser != null){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mCurser.moveToPosition(position)){
       return position;
    }
    if (mCurserImage.moveToPosition(position)){
        return position;
    }

    return position;
}

}
```

Comment: So, I've built a ArrayList as an helper (option 3) where I alternately add Events and Images with their IDs and use it as the main count for the recyclerview adapter. Depending on which type I call my sql tables and set the layout and data. I am not sure if this is the best way, so I still open for tipps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now realized it in two ways:

First with a helper array, which stores the ID of my two SQL tables sorted. This helper is then used as reference for the RecyclerView. Within the RecyclerView I have one ViewHolder for events and one for images. Inside this I refer with the IDs to my SQL tables.

The second way is via nested RecyclerViews. The first one takes the events as input and links within onBindViewHolder to the second RecyclerView with the images as input. The advantage: I don't need an Array Helper and the two views are completely independent from each other. So I can even create a vertical RecyclerView with a horizontal one inside.

I think the second variant is the more elegant one here.

I leave this here (although I could answer it myself after some more research) in case someone has a similar question.